# Javascript trigger when using poltergiest/capybara outside of rails

Tags: ruby, rspec, phantomjs, capybara, poltergeist

I'm using Capybara, rspec and poltergeist, outside of rails, to run some headless integrations tests. The scenario is that, there are 2 select fields. If I select a value in the first select field, the 2nd select field is populated based on the value of the first select field. If I run my spec using poltergeist in Mac OSX, the spec works. But in ubuntu, it fails, it seems that the 2nd select field is not populated. I also have `js: true` on my specs.

Here's my spec_helper.rb:

```
require 'capybara/poltergeist'
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'pry'
require 'support/session_helper'
RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.include Capybara::DSL
  config.include Capybara::Poltergeist
  config.include SessionHelper

  Capybara.run_server = false
  Capybara.default_driver = :poltergeist
  Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
  Capybara.app_host = "http://vps-staging.dropmysite.com"

  options = { js_errors: false }
  Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
    Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, options)
  end

  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|

    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end

end
```

*EDIT* Adding failing spec

```
require 'spec_helper'

feature 'vps-staging', js: true do
  background do
    visit '/'
  end

  let(:timestamp) { Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S') }


  feature 'create private server' do
    background do
      sign_in 'blahblah@blahblah.com'
    end

    it 'successfully creates server' do
      find(:xpath, "//a[@href='/en/private_servers/new']").click

      directory_field = all(".tagit-new")[0].find("input")
      select 'Ubuntu', from: 'distribution'
      select '15.04', from: 'version'
      fill_in 'private_server_profile_name', with: "Auto Test #{timestamp}"
      directory_field.set "/home"
      click_button 'Save'

      visit '/en/dashboard'

      expect(page.text).to have_content "Auto Test #{timestamp}"
    end
  end
end
```

*EDIT* another thing I found out is that, this bug only happens on phantomjs version 1.9.8 and below. 2.0 works fine.

Comment: Could you add a `sleep 5` after populating the field to verify that it is a waiting problem?

Comment: Already tried that, still error. The whole error is this: `Failure/Error: select '15.04', from: 'version'. Capybara::ElementNotFoun: Unable to find option "15.04"`

Comment: It will help to [capture a screenshot](https://github.com/mattheworiordan/capybara-screenshot#manual-screenshots) at the moment of failure. Also, could you add the failing test in the question?

Comment: i'll try and capture a screenshot, but for now, i have updated my question to include the failing spec.

Comment: Why don't you just use the newer version then?

Comment: @ndn: Going to try it now. But I would like to be able to solve this problem because the only instruction that i can find on how to install 2.0 is to manually install it which takes a lot of time.

Comment: What version of poltergeist are you using?   1.7 was just released which has some changes/fixes around select box behavior/events.   Also, does "15.04" happen to be in an optgroup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tom Walpole pointed out, updating poltergeist from 1.6.0 to 1.7.0 fixed most of my problem but I still need to tweak a bit to fully solve my problem. What I did is to create a `js` file to hold the [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Polyfill) and edit my `spec_helper.rb` and tell poltergeist to use the options, `extensions` and include the polyfill.js thus changing this code from

```
options = { js_errors: false }
  Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
    Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, options)
  end
```

to

```
options = { js_errors: false, extensions: ["spec/support/polyfill.js"] }
  Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
    Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, options)
  end
```